# How to write a short code to navigate through 2D array for a condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `10*10` 2D numpy array/list where some values are 0 and others are 1. No two 1 can be set diagonally, which means if `array[3][4]` is 1,then `array[2][4]`, `array[4,4]`, `array[3][3]` and `array[3][5]` can't be 1. So I write this code:

```
if arr[i,j]:
    if arr[i+1,j] or arr[i-1,j] or arr[i,j-1] or arr[i,j+1]:
        return False
```

But the problem is I can't loop through this code all the way from `i = 0` to `i = 9` because for `i = 0` and `i = 9` there will be `list out of index` error.
So I had to rewrite the code:

```
if arr[i,j]:
    if (i>0 and i<9) and (j>0 and j<9):
        if arr[i+1,j] or arr[i-1,j] or arr[i,j-1] or arr[i,j+1]:
            return False
```

And then I have to write a `if-else` for `i==0 and j==0`, then for `i==0 and j==9` and then for `i == 0 and (j > 0 or j < 9)` and some more.
Can anybody suggest a shortcut way to solve the problem in one `if-else` condition without getting the `list out of index` error.

Comment: nested `if` statements, e.g. `if cond1: if cond2: if cond3` is equivalent to `if cond1 and cond2 and cond3:` if you really think a single `if` block is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Okay let me try

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a convolution across your matrix with 0.5 on the diagonals and wherever it returns a 1, there are two ones in a diagonal at that position.

example:

```
array = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                  [1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0]])
```

applying a convolution to the main diagonal direction (\):

```
from scipy.signal import convolve    
convolve(array, np.array([[0.5, 0],[0,0.5]]), mode="valid")
```

output:

```
array([[0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 0. ]])
```

There are no '1's so this passes

Now applying in the other direction (the anti-diagonal, /)

```
convolve(array, np.array([[0, 0.5],[0.5,0]]), mode="valid")
```

output:

```
array([[1. , 0.5],
       [0. , 0. ]])
```

There is a 1 on the top left square of this convolution, so there are two 1's in the anti-diagonal of the original array in the top left corner.

Comment: That's a clever solution. So you would wrap this all inside a function : `def is_correct(array): return (convolve(array, np.array([[0.5, 0],[0,0.5]]), mode="valid") != 1).all() and (convolve(array, np.array([[0, 0.5],[0.5,0]]), mode="valid") != 1).all()`